# How to differentiate the Taylor expansion?

Tags: taylor-expansion

We know the Taylor expansion of $f(x)$ at $a$ is and let it be $g(x)$, then

$$g(x)=f(a)+\frac{f'(a)}{1!}(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+\frac{f'''(a)}{3!}(x-a)^3+\ldots$$

My question is, is it correct if I say

$$g'(x)=\frac{f''(a)}{1!}(x-a)+\frac{f'''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+\frac{f''''(a)}{3!}(x-a)^3+\ldots$$

I think it is wrong because it is multiplied by power of $(x-a)$ for each term. If it is wrong, how can I fix it? Do I have to use product rule of differentiation for each term?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hint: Differentiate according to $x$, not according to $f'(a)$. So for each object of the expansion, only differentiate the part $(x-a)^k$, since all the rest are constants.

Comment: You don't need a product rule. The terms $f^n(a)$ are constants, so you only need to differentiate the $(x-a)$ terms.

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things:

- take the derivative of $g(x)$, term-wise (recall that the series is a function of $x$, not $a$):

$$g'(x)=0+\frac{f'(a)}{1!}1+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}2(x-a)+\frac{f'''(a)}{3!}3(x-a)^2+\ldots\\
={f'(a)}+\frac{f''(a)}{1!}(x-a)+\frac{f'''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+\ldots$$

- develop the Taylor series of $f'(x)$, instead of that of $f(x)$, giving

$$h(x)=f'(a)+\frac{f''(a)}{1!}(x-a)+\frac{f'''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+\frac{f''''(a)}{3!}(x-a)^3+\ldots$$

Interestingly (but without surprise), you get the same expressions.

For a well-behaved Taylor series, the development of the derivative and the derivative of the development do coincide.

Answer (score 0):

It looks wrong and to fix it just differentiate g(x). You don't even have to use product rule because you dont have product of two functions to be differentiated since $f^|(a)$ or other derivatives of f at a are constants.

Answer (score 0):

$f^{n}(a)$ is a constant, so you get for $g'(x)$ the following expression:
$$g'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{f^{k}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^{k-1}k.$$